# Save returned distinct query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, distinct, nosql

I have an attribute in MongoDB which is emotion and takes natural values, for example 1,2,3,5,9...

My objective is to save those values after researching them in MongoDB with a distinct query:

```
db.getSiblingDB('Cast').gmap.distinct('emotion')
db.getSiblingDB('Berlin').gmap.distinct('emotion')
db.getSiblingDB('Enterface').gmap.distinct('emotion')
```

The idea was something like this:

```
var a = db.getSiblingDB('Cast').gmap.distinct('emotion').toArray()
var b = db.getSiblingDB('Berlin').gmap.distinct('emotion').toArray()
var c = db.getSiblingDB('Enterface').gmap.distinct('emotion').toArray()
```

And then insert the returned values into a new collection, for example:

```
db.prueba.insert(a)
```

The output:

```
[ NumberInt(1), NumberInt(2), NumberInt(3), NumberInt(4), NumberInt(5), NumberInt(6), NumberInt(7) ]
```

But this is imposible in MongoDB. Any way to do? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us sample documents or the values return by  `.distinct`? btw `distinct` returns array no need to use `.toArray()` here.

Comment: Please don't post additional informations in the comment. Use the [edit ](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37282277/edit) link on your question to update your post. Also please provide the expected output after insertion.

Comment: Added the following output to the post.

Comment: You need to associate that value with a key